# PHP sending two emails

Tags: php, email

I have this code I put together from other scripts and stuff I found on the internet,

Somehow it is sending me two emails, one email when I just load the page, the second of course when I submit.

Also, the `header()` is not sending me to the page I want it to...it just stays on the same form page, if anyone can help me find out what is going on, it would be much appreciated, I think it does have something to do with the post to self, but I can not for the love of me figure it out!

Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
h6
{
  font-family: bookman old style;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h5
{
  font-family: bookman old style;
  font-size:15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
</style>

<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr  = $websiteErr = $categoryErr = "";
$name = $email = $comment  = $website = $category = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
     $websiteErr = "URL is required";
   } else {
     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
       $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["category"])) {
     $categoryErr = "Category is required";
   } else {
     $category = test_input($_POST["category"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
<?php include'header.php'?>
<h6>Link Submission</h6>
<h5><span class="error">* required field.</span>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name Of Site: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   URL: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Description: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
Category Of Site: <select size="1" name="category"> 
   <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"> -- Please select -- </option>    
   <option>Arts</option>     
   <option>Business</option>     
   <option>Computers</option>     
   <option>Games</option>     
   <option>Health</option>     
   <option>Home</option>     
   <option>Kids and Teens</option>     
   <option>News</option>     
   <option>Recreation</option>     
   <option>Reference</option>     
   <option>Science</option>     
   <option>Shopping</option>     
   <option>Society</option>     
   <option>Sports</option>     
   <option>World</option>

  </select><span class="error">* <?php echo $categoryErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</h5><?php include'footer.php'?>
<?php
$myemail = "links@loadsofads.com";
$subject = "Link Submission";
$message = "Your Link Submission form has been submitted by:
Website Name: $name
E-mail: $email
URL: $website
Category: $category
Description:
$comment";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
header('Location: submitthanks.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why is your code all over at the bottom , you should separate things a little bit. try adding `exit()` after redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sending you two emails because you need to set your entire code inside a conditional statement.

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in conjunction with your already named submit button, which will only send mail once the submit button has been clicked and not on page load.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Modify to:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$myemail = "links@loadsofads.com";
$subject = "Link Submission";
$message = "Your Link Submission form has been submitted by:
Website Name: $name
E-mail: $email
URL: $website
Category: $category
Description:
$comment";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

header('Location: submitthanks.php');
exit;
}
```

---

In regards to the header not redirecting is because you are outputting before header, which if [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) had been set/on, would throw a `Headers already sent...` warning.

Adding [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of your page and set inside `<?php` `?>` tags sometimes help, and placed above `<!DOCTYPE html...`

I.e.:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html ...
```

You would be better off using an form action to another page instead of on the same page, and putting your mail codes in that file.

Another option would be to use a meta refresh method instead, if you wish to use your present code and not use a second page as the mail handler.

For example and in place of `header()`:

```
$url = "submitthanks.php";

print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL=$url\">";
```

---

**Edit:** - rewrite #2

Be sure to change this line `$myemail = "email@example.com";` to be your Email address.

Plus, there was a [**`mail()` header**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) missing which would most likely send mail to Spam,
and added a `from Name` so it's more personalized.

```
<?php

ob_start(); // prevents headers already sent warning

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
h6
{
  font-family: bookman old style;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h5
{
  font-family: bookman old style;
  font-size:15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
</style>

<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr  = $websiteErr = $commentErr = $categoryErr = "";
$name = $email = $comment  = $website = $category = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {

     $nameErr = "Name is required";

$Error = 1;


   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {

       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {

     $emailErr = "Email is required";

$Error = 1;


   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 

 $Error = 1;


     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["website"])) {

     $websiteErr = "URL is required";

$Error = 1;

   } else {
     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {

       $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 

     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {

     $commentErr = "Comment is required";

$Error = 1;

   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }

   if ($_POST["category"] == "" ) {

     $categoryErr = "Category is required";

$Error = 1;

   } else {
     $category = test_input($_POST["category"]);
   }

} // brace for if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
  }
?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
<?php  include 'header.php'; ?>
<h6>Link Submission</h6>
<h5><span class="error">* required field.</span>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name Of Site: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   URL: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Description: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea><span class="error">* <br><?php echo $commentErr;?></span>
   <br><br>

Category Of Site: <select size="1" name="category"> 
   <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"> -- Please select -- </option>    
   <option>Arts</option>     
   <option>Business</option>     
   <option>Computers</option>     
   <option>Games</option>     
   <option>Health</option>     
   <option>Home</option>     
   <option>Kids and Teens</option>     
   <option>News</option>     
   <option>Recreation</option>     
   <option>Reference</option>     
   <option>Science</option>     
   <option>Shopping</option>     
   <option>Society</option>     
   <option>Sports</option>     
   <option>World</option>

  </select><span class="error">* <?php echo $categoryErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
</h5><?php  include 'footer.php'; ?>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if ($Error != 1){

$myemail = "email@example.com";
$subject = "Link Submission";
$message = "Your Link Submission form has been submitted by:
Website Name: $name
E-mail: $email
URL: $website
Category: $category
Description:
$comment";

$headers = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
 header('Location: submitthanks.php');

    } // brace for if ($Error != 1)

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
```

Comment: Ok I tried all that...each step...but the $url one you said instead of header() well once you get to the form, if the user doesn't input anything which is required it goes directly to the thank you page, the other ISSET above that one doesn't work.

Comment: @ElaineN Reload and look under **Edit:** it works. It answers your original question. In regards to validating, that's another story and I don't have time tonight to do a complete test and a rewrite, it's past midnight and I have to go to sleep. I believe my edit will fix the redirection issue and the page load mail send, which I've tested. For a quick fix, you can add `required` to your form elements that need to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put this part of your code in the post section

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $myemail = "links@loadsofads.com";
    $subject = "Link Submission";
    $message = "Your Link Submission form has been submitted by:
    Website Name: $name
    E-mail: $email
    URL: $website
    Category: $category
    Description:
    $comment";
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
    header('Location: submitthanks.php');
```

Comment: I do not understand where I have to put it.

Comment: ok I put it in, but now when validating it sends me a blank form before the changes by the user makes the changes or additions